# convert value int decimal

Tags: javascript, web, asp-classic

Hi I really need your help.

currently i used this code to do auto calculate.

But then I got 8.749999999999998 as an answer.(prefer to be 8.75)
I tried to use fixed to two and still got the same answer.

```
<span name="epr_fctot"  id="epr_fctot" class="medium" size="15">
<script  type="text/javascript">
function fcFunction() {

var fc_airticket =parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_airticket").value)
var fc_accomodation =parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_accomodation").value)
var fc_allowance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_allowance").value)
var fc_transport = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_transport").value)
var fc_entertainment =parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_entertainment").value)
var fc_other = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fc_other").value)

var x = parseFloat(fc_airticket) + parseFloat(fc_accomodation)+parseFloat(fc_allowance)+ parseFloat(fc_transport)+parseFloat(fc_entertainment)+ parseFloat(fc_other);

document.getElementById("epr_fctot").innerHTML = x


}
</script>

</span></label></td>
```

Comment: **document.getElementById("epr_fctot").innerHTML = x.toFixed(2)** didn't work ?

Comment: it works after i removed all the  parseFloat since I save the value in float.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like that..
For strings-

```
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
```

For Numbers, I have made a function..

```
Number.prototype.round = function(num) {
 num= num || 10;
  return parseFloat( this.toFixed(num) );
};
```

Apply in your condition as-

```
x.round(2)
```

## EDIT

You can also try this one..

```
Math.round(x * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Its not a good practice to override prototype atomic types like strings, bools, etc.

Comment: [Agustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4591006/agustin) I have edited some. You can check this up.

Comment: My apologies to [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) , I shouldn't have done that. I am really sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's gone now. Such things are not a part of a good answer. Also OP gets notified when an answer is posted, only that some of new users will be next seen tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your kind. Actually I am newbie to stackoverflow. [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu)

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I just removed parseFloat and use 
document.getElementById("epr_fctot").innerHTML = x.toFixed(2) . and its work well.